# Adding text that contains a dash "-" to a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, combobox

I am dynamically creating a WPF form in c# using a grid.  I have a combobox that is also editable.  I am adding database instances to this combobox.  However when I try to do this add:

```
cbxDBInstances.Items.Add("xx-server\\instance")
```

Gives me an error.  If I remove the dash, "-", it adds just fine.

I have another WPF application where I use xaml to create my controls and I can do this add just fine.

Any ideas on why the dash is causing an issue?  Any idea on how to get around it?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: *"Gives me an error"* ***What*** error? What gives you the error? The compiler? Runtime? Some bloke who wandered in?

Comment: My virus protection pops up with SAPE.Heur,AE935 virus message, And in my error list I get this multiple times:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Could not copy "obj\Debug\DataCleaner.exe" to "bin\Debug\DataCleaner.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. Could not find file 'obj\Debug\DataCleaner.exe'. DataCleaner

Comment: This says it is a warning but fails after 10 retrys.

Comment: Your antivirus is preventing the debugger to run the exe. A weird problem though...

Comment: It is very weird, because when I just remove the dash from the string it works.

Comment: My gut is that I setup the dynamic controls and grid incorrectly or something like that.